# Pip3 install pygame not working

Tags: installation, pip, pygame

I have a Macbook running OS X 10.6 and I am trying to install pygame using pip3 install pygame.

Using python 3.7 and pip 18.0.

Below are the errors from the console.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/Z6/Z6RVS9IMHG4+tkl202dsTU+++TM/-Tmp-/pip-install-ftjsil2g/pygame/setup.py", line 609, in <module>
        setup(**PACKAGEDATA)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 78, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 309, in run
        customize_compiler(self.compiler)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 170, in customize_compiler
        _osx_support.customize_compiler(_config_vars)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/_osx_support.py", line 418, in customize_compiler
        _find_appropriate_compiler(_config_vars)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/_osx_support.py", line 191, in _find_appropriate_compiler
        "Cannot locate working compiler")
    SystemError: Cannot locate working compiler
```

---

```
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/Z6/Z6RVS9IMHG4+tkl202dsTU+++TM/-Tmp-/pip-install-ftjsil2g/pygame/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/Z6/Z6RVS9IMHG4+tkl202dsTU+++TM/-Tmp-/pip-record-vgz3goci/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/Z6/Z6RVS9IMHG4+tkl202dsTU+++TM/-Tmp-/pip-install-ftjsil2g/pygame/
```

Edit: Fixed formatting!

Comment: Have you installed Python3 AND pip3? Mac OSX only comes with Python 2.7.

Comment: I thought python3 comes with pip3

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't, if you use the install from python.org with the installer then it does but on the command line in Linux for example you will sometimes need to also download pip separate.

Comment: run `python3 -v` and `pip3 -v` to check your versions. It could also be that you don't have python3 in your PATH.

Comment: Also can you please format your error messages. Just select them and press `ctrl+k`. They are very hard to read in the current format.

Comment: Whenever I try to format it, it tells me that it is mostly code. Also, I have python 3.7 and pip 18.0 in my PATH.

Comment: Well take a look at my answer and see if that helps. If not I’ll edit it.

Comment: Try uninstalling python, and reinstalling it on the path

Answer (score 0):

So I don't entirely understand what's going on with your error messages but I would recommend checking out this article as it covers setting up Pygame on Mac OSX 10.6-10.9 pretty well.

http://brysonpayne.com/2015/01/10/setting-up-pygame-on-a-mac/

If the above doesn't work, then follow the instructions bellow.

---

Note: I am covering every step so just skip the ones you have already done

**Step 1**: Install Python 3 and Pip

Download Python 3.7 here: [Python 3.7.0](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/python-3.7.0-macosx10.9.pkg).

Run the installer and make sure to select pip (I can't remember if this is optional or not).

**Step 2**: Install Pygame

Run the following command to install Pygame with pip:

```
python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user
```

**Step 3**: Test Pygame Installation

Run this command to test if Pygame installed correctly:

```
python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens
```

Comment: I can't get Xcode because my os is too old, and I also can't get homebrew. This is what happens:                                                             -e:1: Invalid char `\342' in expression
-e:1: Invalid char `\200' in expression
-e:1: Invalid char `\234' in expression

Comment: When I try python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user it has the same error as the one in my question

Comment: That's weird, I just went through the steps on my own machine and and it worked for me. Also just to double check, you have `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin` in you PATH?

Comment: Actually I didn't have it so I just added it, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177832/discussion-between-k-log-and-f-m).

Answer (score 0):

**At the moment, 5/1/2020, you cannot install the pygame libraries in python 3.8 with pip install pygame, but you can install them with a particular version of them, still for dev.**

You can install Python 3.8 in the command line using this version:

```
*pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6*
```

Latest version:

```
*pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev10*
```

And you can check it with
Terminal:

```
$ python3
>>import pygame
pygame 2.0.0.dev10 (SDL 2.0.12, python 3.8.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
```